# Can we open google play store subscription screen from other app?

Tags: android, google-play, subscription, android-inapp-purchase

I want to open google subscription screen from my android app.
Is there any way to open this?

I know that app listing (play store) can be open from our app, but don't know 
about a subscription screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can.
If a user doesn't have any such subscriptions within your app, direct them to the page showing all of their other subscriptions.

[`http://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions`](http://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions)

If, on the other hand, a user does have a non-expired subscription, you can navigate them directly to their subscription

[`https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions?sku=your-sub-product-id&package=your-app-package`](https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions?sku=your-sub-product-id&package=your-app-package)